# 'Find Cycle in Directed Graph' algorithm not working in a particular leetcode problem. Error-"AddressSanitizer:StackOverflow on a particular address"

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search

Question link:
[course schedule leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/course-schedule/)

The question clearly boils down to finding if there is a cycle. I saw the algorithm for that in Tushar Roy's youtube channel but I am struggling to implement it. His idea was if I encounter an element already present in the stack (of nodes being explored) then there is a cycle. His implementation was in Java.

His solution:
[CycleInDirectedGraph.java](https://github.com/mission-peace/interview/blob/master/src/com/interview/graph/CycleInDirectedGraph.java)

```cpp
class Solution {
public:

    bool canFinish(int n, vector<vector<int>>& prerequisites) 
    {
        vector<vector<int>> adj(n,vector<int>());
        for(auto x:prerequisites)
        {
            adj[x[1]].push_back(x[0]);
        }
        unordered_set<int> whiteset;
        unordered_set<int> greyset;
        unordered_set<int> blackset;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            whiteset.insert(i);
        }
        int c=0;
        while(!whiteset.empty())
        {
            if(dfs(*whiteset.begin(), greyset, whiteset, blackset,adj)) {
                c=1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(c==1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;

    }
    bool dfs(int x,unordered_set<int> &greyset,unordered_set<int> &whiteset,unordered_set<int> &blackset,vector<vector<int>> &adj)
    {
        changeset(x,whiteset,greyset);
        for(auto y:adj[x])
        {
            if(blackset.find(y)!=blackset.end())
                continue;
            if(greyset.find(y)!=greyset.end())
                return true;
            if(dfs(x,greyset,whiteset,blackset,adj))
                return true;

        }
        changeset(x,greyset,blackset);
        return false;
    }
    void changeset(int x,unordered_set<int> &a,unordered_set<int> &b)
    {
        a.erase(x);
        b.insert(x);
    }
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'not working'. Does the code compile? If no, what are the errors? If yes, can you provide an input example where this code fails?

Comment: *not working* is not a problem description. In what specific way is it not working?

Comment: hey i am really sorry.i editted the question.it is a runtime error something about stack overflow.i am a beginner so have no idea.

Comment: Thanks @AnandSyam but you will need to provide the main function with the input that cause the error.

Comment: Leetcode doesn't provide the main function.It is not even passing the first test case.I am sorry.